# From an array of objects, extract value of two properties into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider a JavaScript object array with the following structure:
`objArray = [ { foo: 1, bar: 2, anotherfoo:5}, { foo: 3, bar: 4, anotherfoo: 8}];`

How can I use map to extract foo and anotherfoo into a new array.
 [Possible duplicate of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: From your example, what would you want the output to be? `myfunction(objArray)` == what?

Comment: I need another array to have this output: newArray=[{foo:1, anotherfoo:5},{foo:3, anotherfoo:8}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work - if your elements don't have a `foo` or `anotherfoo` they'll come out as `undefined`

```js
objArray = [{
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  anotherfoo: 5
}, {
  foo: 3,
  bar: 4,
  anotherfoo: 8
}];

function myfunction(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(e) {
    return {
      foo: e.foo,
      anotherfoo: e.anotherfoo
    };
  });
}

newArray = myfunction(objArray);
console.log(newArray);

// newArray is [{foo:1, anotherfoo:5},{foo:3, anotherfoo:8}]
```

If you're using modern JS (ES6 I think) you can use 'object destructuring'

```
function myfunction2(arr) {
  return arr.map(({foo, anotherfoo}) => 
                 ({foo, anotherfoo}));
}
```

to be honest I think the old way is clearer in intent.

To address your comment - if you want to do some further processing - it's easy if you just need one element at a time. That's what `Array.map` does, it breaks the array into its elements, runs a function on each one, and re-assembles the return values into another array of the same size.

```
function myfunction(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(e) {
    var newfoo;
    if(e.foo==="something") {newfoo = anotherfoo+1;} else{newfoo = anotherfoo-1;}
    return {
      foo: e.foo,
      anotherfoo: newfoo
    };
  });
}
```

and with destructuring

```
function myfunction2(arr) {
  return arr.map(({foo, anotherfoo}) => {
                   if(foo==="something") {anotherfoo+=1} else{anotherfoo -=1};
                   return {foo, anotherfoo}});
}
```

Obviously if your processing function gets too big you can break it out into another standalone function instead of giving an anonymous function to `map`

Comment: Great answer. If I want to do some calculation on the properties of the object array how to do it. Something like if(foo==="something") {anotherfoo+=1} else{anotherfoo -=1}. and then return with the same structure as before.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr.map(({foo, anotherfoo}) => ({foo, anotherfoo}))
```